# Is it possible to use pinch zoom to change the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android app where I have a grid of 4x4 ImageViews. I want to implement a pinch-zoom functionality wherein I can pinch zoom to change the layout to 2x2 Imageviews and pinch-zoom further to just 1 (or  1x1 image view). My question is: is this possible? (Sorry, if it sounds like a noob, I haven't implemened the pinch zoom on android before) If yes, could someone please provide me some pointers that might help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible? Yes! Simple? Absolutely No! Maybe apply a crude zoom during the pinch and on certain thresholds change the fragment for one with the gridview with right number of  columns. Maybe extend some magic with the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html . Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but if you are looking for it to smoothly zoom it could be quite tricky and interesting. If you are happy to just detect a pinch zoom and switch layout, then it's simple enough. Detecting it is done with the [ScaleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html)